# Modificar ficheros remotos

Tags: java

Buenas, estoy accediendo a archivos que tengo en una carpeta compartida en una unidad de red, y para no montar el disco en cada pc creo un objecto de la clase File de la siguiente manera:

```
File f = new File("file://190.10.10.240/Cedulas/").
```

Tengo acceso a los archivos, al ejecutar el código pertinente abre y puedo trabajar con ellos, pero cuando quiero renombrar el archivo no lo hace.
Anteriormente los tenia así:

```
File f = new File("S:/190.10.10.240/Cedulas/");
```

y me el rename lo hacía sin problema

```
f.renameTo(f2);
```

Alguna idea del porque?

Comment: Hola Carlos. No está claro lo que preguntas.. Puedes explicar que intentas y por qué no lo consigues o qué esperas de tu función? y qué es `f2`? Un saludo

Comment: Es posible que tengas permisos de edición pero no de creación, y el sistema operativo entienda el renombrado como la creación de un nuevo fichero. ¿Puedes comprobar que tienes permisos de creación?

Comment: Ah disculpa. Lo que intento hacer es renombrar un archivo que se encuentra en una unidad de red, la cual desmonte de mi equipo. Para acceder a la unidad y obtener el fichero hago lo siguiente: File f = new File("file://190.10.10.240/Cedulas/cedula1.pdf") . Luego creo un nuevo objeto File con el cual renombraré el anterior: File f2 = new File("file://190.10.10.240/Cedulas/cedula2.pdf"). Para renombrarlo hago esto: f.renameTo(f2). Puedo visualizar pero no me deja modificar por esta vía, en cambio, cuando accedia localmente montando la unidad en mi PC, renombraba sin problema.

Comment: Gracias Pablo, me voy a fijar en tu propuesta.

Comment: Carlos, ese comentario grande tuyo deberia ser parte de la pregunta, ya que en la pregunta deberia estar todo lo relevante para su resolucion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

buenas!

Si el ordenador que tiene la carpeta compartida es windows, me parece que puede ser a causa de que cuanado mapeas el directorio como unidad de red, este usa las credenciales del usuario para acceder manteniéndolas "abiertas".Mientras que al acceder directamente al archivo sin mapeo de Red necesitarás pasar de alguna manera tus credenciales, puedes probar con esto:

```
String credenciales = "user:password";
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(credenciales);
String f1= "smb://190.10.10.240/Cedulas/test.txt";
String f2= "smb://190.10.10.240/Cedulas/testRename.txt";
SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(f1, auth);
SmbFile smbFileRename = new SmbFile(f2, auth);
smbFile.rename(smbFileRename);
```

Comment: Gracias Miguel por tu respuesta que fue la solución a mi problema. Usuario y password eran mi problema